# The returned head for merging two sorted linked lists

Tags: python, pointers, linked-list

The following is a python function to merge two sorted linked lists. I know that in python a variable name is a reference/pointer to an object. Can anyone explain to me that:

"tail" points to head3. In the code "tail" keeps changing and head3 seems like not involved in actions. How does head3 automatically connect to the merged list? Why does head3 change only once when it's related to "tail"?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

def merge_sorted(head1, head2):
    head3 = Node(None)
    tail = head3

    if head1 is None:
        tail.next = head2
    if head2 is None:
        tail.next = head1

    while head1 and head2:
        if head1.data <= head2.data:
            tail.next = head1
            head1 = head1.next
        else:
            tail.next = head2
            head2 = head2.next
        tail = tail.next

    return head3.next
```

Comment: Have you tried dry-running this? Try running it on http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html with sample data.

Comment: @Quirk Not bad. Thanks for the help.